# Fading away from curve using fillbetween library

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I have two paths defined that I would like to have filled and have fading. I want the fading to be 100% along some curve, and then fading as it gets further away from that curve. So specifying [top color, bottom color, etc] is not going to be sufficient here.

The following code produces the plot below, but I want red!50 to be along the log(x) curve.

Any idea how to achieve this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  
  \begin{axis}[xmin=1, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=1]
    \addplot[red, domain=1:10, name path=constraint] {log10(x)};
    \path[name path=edge] (axis cs:1,1) -- (axis cs:10,1);
    \addplot [bottom color=red!50, top color=white] 
      fill between [of=edge and constraint];
  \end{axis}   
      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: fading along a curve seems to be difficult, even with TikZ! I have never seen it before